# Create a new package directory inside Android/data directory not part of own android application

Tags: android

I have a library with package name as com.xyz.abc package name. I want to programmatically create a file inside /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xyz.abc/file.txt which is not part of my application package or my application

I have written the below code:

```
     String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xyz.abc";

     File file = new File(filePath);

     if (!file.exists()) {

     if (file.mkdir()) {
         saveFile(filePath);
     }
     } else {
         saveFile(filePath);
     }

        private void saveFile(String filePath) {
    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        File saveFilePath = new File(filePath + "/" + "file.txt");
        // clear the previous logcat and then write the new one to the file
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + saveFilePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
         /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When i see the directory the package com.xyz.abc is not saved in the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/"

Is it possible to create a package outside of my application in Android/data directory. If so how can i do that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just create those folders in the usual way. Not possible on an Android 11 device.

Comment: `boolean b = file.canWrite();  ` You dont use b. But worse, if that directory does not exist then using canWrite makes no sense. Try to create the directory first if it does not exist.

Comment: `The boolean returns as false` Use that in your code. `if (!b) return;`

Comment: @blackapps My issue is that the package package com.xyz.abc is not saved in this path /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ and the folder is not getting created

Comment: What do you mean with not saved? Do you mean that the folder  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ com.xyz.abc does not exist? And if so that you can not create it? Or does the folder exist and now you wanna save a file in it and the file can not be created? Of course you should first care for an existing folder before you try to save files in it. You are not doing that at the moment. Further you did not react to the point to my three comments.

Comment: The folder needs to be created newly with the package name com.xyz.abc under Android/data, yes i cannot create it, and i want to save a file in it.

Comment: You are not trying to create it. You should add code for that first. I told you that before but you are not reacting on those comments.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for helping. I created a directory using mkdir based on your previous comments. This code works on Android 5.1.1 but it doesnot create directory in Android 9. Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Throw away that function isExternalStorageWritable() to begin with. Adapt your code here too.

Comment: `if (!file.mkdir()){Toast(....could not create directory...); return;}`  Please adapt your code. Also here. Call saveFile() only once.

Comment: @blackapps Can you help me know why the folder is not getting creating in Android 9?

Comment: I just did. But if you do not adapt your code and just let me talk...